# Error in frequency table in R

Tags: r, frequency

I have a dataframe which is as follow:

```
   Name   Condition  NumMessage
Table 1        NULL          80 
Table 1        Fair          20
Table 1        Good          60
Table 1       Ideal          50
Table 1       Great          80
Table 2        NULL          80 
Table 2        Fair         100
Table 2        Good          90
Table 2       Ideal          50
Table 2       Great          40
```

and so on. I tried to create a frequency table for the number of message for each table.

```
data = as.data.frame(prop.table(table(dataframe$Name)))
colnames(data) = c('Table Name', 'Frequency')
data
```

but this returns **same frequency for all tables.** For example, Table 1 contains total of 290 messages where Table 2 contains 360 messages. But the above code gives same frequency for both tables.

Also when I tried to get frequency of each condition for each table, I also got same numbers across tables.

```
prop.table(table(dataframe$Condition, dataframe$Name))

NULL   | some value
Fair   | some value  
Good   | some value
Ideal  | some value
Great  | some value
```

is this the correct way to get the frequency of total number of messages for each table and frequency of conditions for each table?

Comment: `prop.table(xtabs(NumMessage ~ Name + Condition, data=df), 1)` or something like that.

Comment: @thelatemail yup, exactly what I was looking for, if you post it as answer, I can select it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xtabs` is the base R way to get a summed contingency table.

```
prop.table(xtabs(NumMessage ~ ., data=df), 1)
#        Condition
#Name           Fair       Good      Great      Ideal       NULL
#  Table1 0.06896552 0.20689655 0.27586207 0.17241379 0.27586207
#  Table2 0.27777778 0.25000000 0.11111111 0.13888889 0.22222222
```

Comment: is it possible to output for total and not each individual table? (in addition to above which is also needed)

Comment: @RainMan - i'm not sure what you mean? Proportion of total? if so, just remove the `,1` and use `prop.table(...)`

Comment: for example, sum the fair, good, great, ieadl and null proportions for all tables. The reason to do so is because I want to do a bar graph with conditions as x axis and proportion as y

Comment: @RainMan - `prop.table(xtabs(NumMessage ~ Condition, data=df))`

Comment: @RainMan I think you need `addmargins` i.e. `addmargins(prop.table(xtabs(NumMessage ~ ., data=df), 1),1)`

Comment: @thelatemail so for fair we should get 0.34...but I am not getting that using that method.

Comment: @akrun yes, that works but it still prints out all tables with their values and sum row at the bottom, is it possible just to output the sum?

Comment: @RainMan In that case do a `colSums` and you will get a vector of values.

Answer (score 3):

We could try with `acast`

```
library(reshape2)
prop.table(acast(df1, Name~Condition, value.var='NumMessage', sum),1)
#                 Fair      Good     Great     Ideal      NULL
#Table 1 0.06896552 0.2068966 0.2758621 0.1724138 0.2758621
#Table 2 0.27777778 0.2500000 0.1111111 0.1388889 0.2222222
```

Answer (score 0):

If we call your dataset df, then perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
df1 = subset(df, Name=='Table1')
df2 = subset(df, Name=='Table2')
prop.table(df1[,3])
prop.table(df2[,3])

aggregate(df1$NumMessage, list(df1$Name), sum)
aggregate(df1$NumMessage, list(df2$Name), sum)
```

Comment: there are 100+ tables, I cant create df for each one

Answer (score 0):

You can always tackle this with the package `sqldf`.

```
library(sqldf)
Name<-c('Table1','Table1','Table1','Table1','Table1','Table2','Table2','Table2','Table2','Table2')
Cond<-c(NA,'Fair','Good','Ideal','Great',NA,'Fair','Good','Ideal','Great')
Msg<-c(80,20,60,50,80,80,100,90,50,40)
df<-data.frame(Name,Cond,Msg)
```

Your dataframe:

```
Name  Cond Msg
1  Table1  <NA>  80
2  Table1  Fair  20
3  Table1  Good  60
4  Table1 Ideal  50
5  Table1 Great  80
6  Table2  <NA>  80
7  Table2  Fair 100
8  Table2  Good  90
9  Table2 Ideal  50
10 Table2 Great  40
```

Now simply use this statement for sum of messages for each table:

```
sqldf("select Name, sum(Msg) from df group by Name ") 

Name sum(Msg)
1 Table1      290
2 Table2      360
```

If you want sum of messages for each condition then use:

```
sqldf("select Cond, sum(Msg) from df group by Cond ")
Cond sum(Msg)
1  <NA>      160
2  Fair      120
3  Good      150
4 Great      120
5 Ideal      100
```

Hope that helps.